# Is patent US 5,356,330 a real patent?

Tags: us5356330

Is [US 5,356,330](http://www.google.com/patents/us5356330) a real patent? The more I research patents, the more I am astounded. I am starting to believe that none of these patents are real. Perhaps this is an elaborate art project created by Google.

Answer (score 1):

The U.S. requirements are *useful*, not already done (*novelty*), and *not obvious* in light of what has already been published. A big improvement, industrial applicability, and earth-shattering are not requirements under U.S. patent law. In this case someone has the right to exclude others from making, selling or using this thing that probably nobody wants to make, sell or use anyway.