# is model is working or demonstrative only?

Tags: patent-applications

In reference to the patent: [US20040130227](https://www.google.com/patents/US20040130227)

Is the model working model or for demonstration model only?

Comment: Please see the [Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) Image File Wrapper for the Final Rejection of this patent (search by Publication Number **US 20040130227 A1**). Also see [this answer](http://patents.stackexchange.com/a/13393/14417) regarding perpetual motion machine patents.